# I got a problem with my render test in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

What is wrong with my render test here ? test and expect is undefined but i see some tutorials and they do the same thing. I'm on a basic create react app.

```
    import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
    import App from "./App"

test("renders learn react link", () => {
  render(<App />)
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i)
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

and my eslint.rc ( i don't know if it's necessary )

```
module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly",
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect",
    },
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 11,
    "sourceType": "module",
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react", "react-hooks",
  ],
  "ignorePatterns": ["__mocks__", "*_pb.js"],
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    "no-trailing-spaces": ["error"],
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "semi": ["error", "never"],
    "comma-dangle": ["error", "always-multiline"],
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react/display-name": "off",
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
  },
}
```

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: @evolutionxbox with npm test

Comment: What does `npm test` run? Are you using create-react-app? Do you have jest installed?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes create react app and jest is installed in "jest": "^27.5.1"

Comment: and npm test run this  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

Comment: That makes sense since you mentioned you're using create-react-app. Have a look here, https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/122, see if it helps?